# JWT token not cleared on the browser even after token expiry or logging out

Tags: angular, authentication, jwt

We have a spring-boot application with Angular 2, and for authentication we use JWT. I am encountering an issue - even after the token has expired and then logging out and login again, the expired JWT token is still available on the request header. So the backend still validates the old JWT token, instead of the new one. I need to clear the browser cache to make it work.

I see that the token is stored in SessionStorage, so did the below to clear the token on `logout()`

```
logout() {
    if (this.principal.isAuthenticated()) {
        sessionStorage.removeItem('authenticationtoken');
        this.authServerProvider.logout().subscribe();            
    }
    this.principal.authenticate(null);
}
```

But this also not clearing the old token. What can I do to clear the token from the browser?

Comment: Make sure that your token is stored in sessionStorage rather than localStorage if so it will be localStorage.removeItem('authenticationtoken')

Comment: @willmaz The token is stored in sessionStorage.

Comment: sessionStorage.removeItem('authenticationtoken') should remove your token from the web storage ... you can try it directly in your browser with F12 -> application -> session storage and than execute the code above in console and verify if the token is already there

Comment: when I click on the logout button, I can see that the token is deleted from F12 -> application -> session storage, but still I receive the old token in the backend.

Comment: Can you add your login service to the post ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through the code, I found out that the headers were defined as "const'. When I changed them to 'let', all started working fine.